# How to do Unit Testring of a BehaviourSubject variable in a service, it is an observable in a component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, components, observable

I am trying to write test cases for a variable(masters) in a component it is a `BehaviorSubject` variable in service. I am not able find a way to write test case. Below are the details

```
// component code
export class MastersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  masters: any[] = [];

  constructor(private masterService: MasterService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    //.... some code here

    this.masterService.masters.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.masters = result;
      });

    //....some code here
    this.getMasters();
  }

  // component method code
  getMasters() => {
    const paginationObject = {
      pageNo: this.pageIndex + 1,
      sizePerPage: this.sizePerPage,
      searchString: this.searchString,
      order: 'asc',
      orderBy: ['name'],
      repositoryId: this.repositoryId
    };
    this.masterService.getMasters(paginationObject, alertError);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.masterService.masters.next([]);
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
}

// service method code
masters: BehaviorSubject<Master[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

getMasters = (paginationObject, fail) => {
    this.resources.getMasters(paginationObject,
      (response) => {
        this.masters.next(response);
      }, (response) => {
        this.masters.next([]);
        fail(response);
      });
  }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: Hi Mike,  Thanks for your response. I am trying to write test cases for masters variable which is declared in MastersComponent. But this variable is an observable and this will get updated in service method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix between your component's field and your service's observable.

As a starter, I would recommend you to test the ngOnInit method. Here's the outline:

1. Create a stub for MasterService which exposes a masters Observable and a getMasters method. This stub method actually functions as the input to ngOnInit, so you should put inside it whatever input you desire to test, for example empty data: "this.masters.next([])"
2. Use your testing framework to inject this stub as MasterService
3. Call ngOnInit
4. Assert that component's masters variable equals to []

To sum up, we have designed the following test case: given empty masters as an external service input, component is also initialized with empty masters.

True, this is a simple test (some will say unnecessary), but it should demonstrate how to test a method that gets an input not as an argument (direct) but as a dependency (service, indirect).

The service, BTW, should also be tested as a separate unit: the "resources" dependency (an indirect input) is to be mocked for the getMasters method to be tested with the two arguments as direct input.